# loops in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, loops

i have two sets of data, say `a=file1 file2 file3` and `b=location1 location2 location3`.
Now i need to loop through and copy `file1` to `location1`, `file2` to `location2` and `file3` to `location3`.

If I use for loop, then after the first iteration of the the inner loop, it should go back to the outer loop, take the second value, go to the inner loop and take the second value and so on. Basically, the inner loop should not iterate for every value in the outer loop.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Sudhir

Comment: where are the lists of files coming from?  Are you walking a directory or a folder?

Comment: which shell (and what version) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're getting too complicated:

```
a=(file1 file2 file3)
b=(location1 location2 location3)

for (( idx=0; idx<${#a[@]}; idx++ )); do
    cp -v "${a[idx]}" "${b[idx]}"
done
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. thanks a ton for your time. i cant use perl as this is a part of a bigger script. thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You can create bash arrays and make it work for you:

```
declare -a f=( "file1" "file2" "file3" )
declare -a d=( "location1" "location2" "location3" )
c=0
for i in ${f[@]}; do
   echo $i ${d[$c]}
   ((c++))
done
```

Or without arrays something like this script should also work for you:

```
ci=0
for i in file1 file2 file3; do 
   ((ci++))
   cj=1
   for j in location1 location2 location3; do
      [[ $ci = $cj ]] && echo $i $j && break
     ((cj++))
   done
done
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
file1 location1
file2 location2
file3 location3
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure `$SHELL` is simplest here, although once you start doing arrays with `bash` that advantage starts to dissipate ;-)  So, just for comparison, here is a simple, non-oneliner `perl` approach:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl
 my @arraya = qw/ file1 file2 file3/ ; 
 my @arrayb = qw/ location1 location2 location3/ ;
 foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#arraya ) {`cp $arraya[$i] $arrayb[$i]` }
```

`@arraya` and `@arrayb` can be constructed programmatically into very large lists with `/m//` matching and filtering, `grep`ing, `find`ing, etc.

*c.f.* the `perl` based [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) tool.